# Set custom shipping rates programmatically in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have searched and found a number of examples of how to change the shipping rates. Basically I am looking to do the same, but I want to use a 3rd party API.

I have set up a custom plugin with a functions.php and activated it.  I think used something simple like this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates','test_overwrite',10,2);
function test_overwrite($rates,$package) {

    echo "<h2>Can you see me</h2>";
    foreach ($rates as $rate) {
        //Set the price
        $rate->cost = 1000;
        //Set the TAX
        $rate->taxes[1] = 1000 * 0.2;
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

However when I run either the checkout, or basket, the filter does not seem to run because I cannot see the `echo`.  I also tried `print_r()`.

Am I missing something as to why I cannot run this filter ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As this is a filter and as the data is cached, you can't get any output with `print_r()`.

The correct way to make it work is the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_shipping_costs', 20, 2 );
function custom_shipping_costs( $rates, $package ) {
    // New shipping cost (can be calculated)
    $new_cost = 1000;
    $tax_rate = 0.2;

    foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
        // Excluding free shipping methods
        if( $rate->method_id != 'free_shipping'){

            // Set rate cost
            $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $new_cost;

            // Set taxes rate cost (if enabled)
            $taxes = array();
            foreach ($rates[$rate_key]->taxes as $key => $tax){
                if( $rates[$rate_key]->taxes[$key] > 0 )
                    $taxes[$key] = $new_cost * $tax_rate;
            }
            $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;

        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme).

Tested and works.

> Sometimes, you should may be need **to refresh shipping methods**:
>   1) Empty cart first.
>   2) Go to shipping Zones settings, then disable/save and re-enable/save the related shipping methods.

Comment: That is great, thank you.  I did not understand about clearing the cache because the price was going to change I had thought it would work.  That said, if I cannot print or echo how do I know what the $package looks like.  So I get total weight, country for the 3rd Party Api ?