# Exclude user role from custom shipping discount in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, shipping-method

Based on [Set custom shipping rates programmatically in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48786788/set-custom-shipping-rates-programmatically-in-woocommerce-3/48787963#48787963) answer code, I modified it in order to add a discount on shipping rates for each seller.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_shipping_methods', 10, 2 );
function custom_shipping_methods( $rates, $package ) {
$reduction_cost_percentage = 30; // Discount percentage
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item  ){
    $in_cart_product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
    $cart_seller_id = get_post_field('post_author', $in_cart_product_id);
    $cart_seller_meta = get_userdata($cart_seller_id);
    $cart_seller_roles = $cart_seller_meta->roles;
    if($cart_seller_roles[0] == 'seller'){
        foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
            if( $rate->method_id != 'free_shipping'){
                $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $rates[$rate_key]->cost * ((100-$reduction_cost_percentage) / 100); 
                return $rates;
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to exclude this discount from a certain role for example `seller_2`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some mistakes and oversights in your code, try the following instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_shipping_methods', 10, 2 );
function custom_shipping_methods( $rates, $package ) {
    // Loop through cart items for the current package
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $cart_item ){
        $seller_id    = get_post_field('post_author', $cart_item['product_id']);
        $seller_data  = get_userdata($seller_id);

        // Excluding product 'seller' user role
        if ( ! empty($seller_data) && is_array($seller_data->roles) && in_array('seller', $seller_data->roles) ) {
            return $rates; // stop the loop and return normally the shipping rates
        }
    }

    $percentage    = 30; // <== Set your discount percentage

    $discount_rate = $percentage / 100;

    // Loop through shipping rates for the current package when seller user role is not found
    foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
        // Not for free shipping
        if( $rate->method_id != 'free_shipping' ){
            // Change rate cost
            $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $rate->cost * $discount_rate;

            $taxes = array(); // Initializing

            // change taxes rate cost (if enabled)
            foreach ($rate->taxes as $key => $tax){
                if( $tax > 0 ){
                    $taxes[$key] = $tax * $discount_rate;
                    $has_taxes = true;
                }
            }
            // Change taxes cost
            if( $has_taxes ) {
                $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). It should works.

> **Clearing shipping caches**:
>
> - You will need to empty your cart, to clear cached shipping data
> - Or In shipping settings, you can disable / save any shipping method, then enable back / save.