# Force free shipping programatically - even when requirement is not met

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

For one day, during the free shipping event, I would like to enable free shipping for every order (using hook / filter) without changing the actual shipping settings inside admin (minimum requirement). I tried using the following snippet, but unfortunately does not work when minimum total for free shipping is not met. Free shipping does not appear inside `$rates`.

```
function force_free_shipping( $rates ) {
    $free = array();
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
        if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
            $free[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
            break;
        }
    }
    return ! empty( $free ) ? $free : $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'force_free_shipping', 200 );
```

Answer (score 1):

My code is taken from this topic ([Set custom shipping rates programmatically in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48786788/set-custom-shipping-rates-programmatically-in-woocommerce-3) , and credit goes to @LoicTheAztec and his answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48787963/17787127) and adjusted. Mine is kinda ugly I guess, but at least it works.

If you only have one shipping method, use this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_shipping_costs', 20, 2 );
function custom_shipping_costs( $rates, $package ) {
    // New shipping cost (can be calculated)
    $new_cost = 0;
    $tax_rate = 0;

    foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
        // Excluding free shipping methods
        if( $rate->method_id != 'shipping_method_0_flat_rate1'){

            // Set rate cost
            $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $new_cost;

            // Set taxes rate cost (if enabled)
            $taxes = array();
            foreach ($rates[$rate_key]->taxes as $key => $tax){
                if( $rates[$rate_key]->taxes[$key] > 0 )
                    $taxes[$key] = $new_cost * $tax_rate;
            }
            $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;

        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

If you have multiple shipping methods use this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_shipping_costs', 20, 2 );
function custom_shipping_costs( $rates, $package ) {
    // New shipping cost (can be calculated)
    $new_cost = 0;
    $tax_rate = 0;

    foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
        // Excluding free shipping methods
        if( $rate->method_id != 'shipping_method_0_flat_rate1'){

            // Set rate cost
            $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $new_cost;

            // Set taxes rate cost (if enabled)
            $taxes = array();
            foreach ($rates[$rate_key]->taxes as $key => $tax){
                if( $rates[$rate_key]->taxes[$key] > 0 )
                    $taxes[$key] = $new_cost * $tax_rate;
            }
            $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;

        } elseif ( $rate->method_id != 'shipping_method_0_flat_rate5'){

            // Set rate cost
            $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $new_cost;

            // Set taxes rate cost (if enabled)
            $taxes = array();
            foreach ($rates[$rate_key]->taxes as $key => $tax){
                if( $rates[$rate_key]->taxes[$key] > 0 )
                    $taxes[$key] = $new_cost * $tax_rate;
            }
            $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;

        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

For both cases you need to replace **shipping_method_0_flat_rate1** and/or **shipping_method_0_flat_rate5** with your shipping method IDs (you can find it with Chrome inspect tool):

[image: shipping_method_id]

In order for the code to work the first time, you *may* have to remove product from cart, add it again and check it.

Code goes in functions.php, tested and works.